# What palm tree is this?

Tags: identification, palm

Looks to be single trunk, self cleaning. The trunk is spotted/mottled and furry. The fronds have jagged leaves. It's not a fishtail, foxtail, rhapis or a kentia(similar)... I am unsure as to the type. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: tree]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's many different kinds of palms.Could be Lady palm Parlor or Reed.All grow anywhere from 3-8 ft.Care is about the same with all,moist soil,no direct sun min. night temps. at 62-65.Fertilize once a month mostly during the growing season.I love palms,remind me of the tropics I have a small one in my bath room.

Answer (score 1):

Leaves look like the Christmas palm, adonidia. When the spotted/mottled look disappears when the palm tree is older, it could be this one...

http://www.palmpedia.net/wiki/Adonidia_dransfieldii